# IBM Worklight 6.0 - "project not initialized" error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8

The following is my setup:

1. WebSphere Application Server v8.0 express Edition
2. IBM DB2 10.1 Server Edition
3. IBM Worklight Server Consumer Edition v6.0
4. Worklight Studio v6.0 Consumer edition Eclipse plug-in
5. JDK 1.7
   To perform installation task i followed the IBM Worklight v6.0.0 infocenter "Installing & Configuring" section.

After Deploying app on the Application Server when i am accessing app using 
localhost:9080/Hello/console it shows the error of "Worklight Project not initialized".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you edit your question and detail how did you install (deploy) Worklight on your copy of WAS. This will help in finding out any possible errors in your steps.

Please make sure that you follow the instructions as given in the IBM Worklight Information Center: [Installing Worklight Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_installation.html)

In addition I've found this technote regarding WAS Liberty, which talks about the same error message: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM88638

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have edited the question.I am looking solution for deployment on Webshpere Application Server.

Comment: Hi Adan is there any solution for this issue?