# Worklight 6 upgrade going haywire

Tags: java, jpa, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

We're currently in the process of upgrading our Studio and Server instances from Worklight 5.0.6 to Worklight 6. I'm setting up the server side on a freshly installed RHEL 6 image using the following middleware. Server installation instructions (outside what was already done in the image) were followed to a T from the official IBM docs for WL6

WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile 8.5
DB2 V9.7 with fixpack 8
Worklight 6.0.0

Studio upgrade went smooth, so no issues there. The bug is happening server side when I'm trying to actually access the application console, and even the installed appcenter war. In both cases the JPA entity resource is coming up with nothing and so I get the following error when trying to access my console:

```
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.annotation.Resource annotation class will not be   
recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product 
class  loader.
[err] 22  WorklightPU  WARN   [Default Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error     
occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU'
```

The installed image was create on a VM with WL6 and WLP pre-installed by the company. I installed DB2 manually, and created all the necessary users, groups, and configurations to ensure connectivity. I then ran the DB2 configuration ant task provided by WL6 to ensure the tables for WorkLight and the Appcenter are created correctly, build successful. I then also ran the install task as well. Build successful.

Here is the server.xml configurations that were added with sensitive information redacted, all created with the ant build scripts.

```
<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Console application. -->
<application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="worklight.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <commonLibrary>
            <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
        </commonLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
```

And the JDBC DB connection configurations

```
<!-- Declare the jar files for DB2 access through JDBC. -->
<library id="worklight/DB2Lib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/db2" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Console database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="worklight/DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WRKLGHT" serverName="db2server.site.com" portNumber="50000" user="user" password="password"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Console Reports database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="worklight/DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WLREPORT" serverName="db2server.site.com" portNumber="50000" user="user" password="password"/>
</dataSource>
```

If needed I can also edit this question to include necessary information from the worklight.properties file associated with my customized war. I greatly appreciate any help!

I was hoping this link would help me, but it's for a totally different issue (and older version of worklight, as the fix says "The fix for this APAR is currently targeted for inclusion in fixpack 5.0.6.0.") [IBM Worklight 6.0 - "project not initialized" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530795/ibm-worklight-6-0-project-not-initialized-error)

EDIT: Tracked this down to more than likely a DB issue. We're getting messages such as:
Adding a gadget activity report failed
And other errors related to the JDBC connections not being valid...even though they are the ones seutp by the WL ANT scripts

Comment: Do you have the JPA feature enabled in your Liberty profile? If yes, can you try w/out it?

Comment: Did you restart Liberty after upgrading?

Comment: We did a fresh install, well sort of, from an existing RHEL image given to us by a certain group at a certain company, so it wasn't part of the upgrade. JPA is not being used as is, so I'm not sure why that error is even there. Which logs would you like to see?
Appreciate the help!

Comment: all logs from the logs folder of the application server?

Comment: Let me see if I can actually give those to you without getting in trouble

Comment: Of course your customer/business parter can just open a PMR, which is the official way surely to get help from IBM...

Comment: By any chance do you have any unwanted .jar files under '${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/db2' that could be causing class loading clashes? Also, since you are not passing the 'currentSchema' property to 'properties.db2.jcc', make sure that the schema used to create the datasource tables match the default server setting.

Comment: Hi @eabe! Definitely setting up the schemas right, went by the book on that one. The idea regarding load clashes came to me today so that's the first thing I'm checking tomorrow, so thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions guys. We figured this out and will be working with the people who make the image (and hopefully the Worklight team itself) to figure out a better way to go about WL6 setups. I see some PMR's, emails, and talks with my PM in the future ;)

Comment: @Zarazthuztra, you may want to change your comment to an answer so you can mark it answered.

Comment: Thanks @Barbara, actually the first question I had ever asked here so I didn't even think to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this ourselves by removing everything from the image and installing ourselves.